# Using a WHILE loop twice / temporarily breaking from a WHILE loop

Tags: php, html, while-loop, slider

Background - Built a WordPress website and have utilised ACF Advanced Custom Fields to generate input fields within my pages.

I have then populated the pages fields so I can generate / use this variable:

```
<?php
    $case_study_image_gallery = get_field('case_study_image_gallery');
?>
```

I then call the subfield in the while loop, then call the ['url'] when using the variable to break up the image array.

```
<?php if( $case_study_image_gallery ) : ?>

    <div class="case-study-slider">
        <?php
            while (have_rows('case_study_image_gallery')): the_row();
            $case_study_image = get_sub_field('case_study_image');
        ?>

            <div class="case-study-slide">
                <img class="case-study-slider-image" src="<?php echo $case_study_image['url']; ?>">
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="case-study-slider-nav">
        <?php
            while (have_rows('case_study_image_gallery')): the_row();
            $case_study_image = get_sub_field('case_study_image');
        ?>

            <div class="case-study-nav-slide">
                <img class="case-study-slider-nav-image" src="<?php echo $case_study_image['url']; ?>">
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see I have broken my while into multiple sections as I need to use the same values for both the slider images and the thumbnail smaller images. In doing so I must place this code between the two uses of the sub field image.

```
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="case-study-slider-nav">
        <?php
            while (have_rows('case_study_image_gallery')): the_row();
            $case_study_image = get_sub_field('case_study_image');
        ?>
```

This OBVIOUSLY wont work as the first loop has burnt through the instances of the images.

I am essentially looking for a way to have a break from the loop without restarting / looping through it and triggering the next row of data. Like this:

```
<?php if( $case_study_image_gallery ) : ?>

<div class="case-study-slider">
    <?php
        while (have_rows('case_study_image_gallery')): the_row();
        $case_study_image = get_sub_field('case_study_image');
    ?>

        <div class="case-study-slide">
            <img class="case-study-slider-image" src="<?php echo $case_study_image['url']; ?>">
        </div>

    <?php 
        HAVE A BREAK FROM THE WHILE; 
    ?>
</div>
<div class="case-study-slider-nav">
    <?php
        CONTINUE WHILE
    ?>

        <div class="case-study-nav-slide">
            <img class="case-study-slider-nav-image" src="<?php echo $case_study_image['url']; ?>">
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

I appreciate there are ways to reset the loop once it has completed but I feel there should be a way to utilise the code how I am trying here.

In responce to Simonw16:

```
<div class="cs-slider">
    <div class="case-study-slider">
        <div class="case-study-slide"><img class="case-study-slider-image" src="https://localhost/materialshub/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/silicone-elastomer-tube.png"></div>
        <div class="case-study-slide"><img class="case-study-slider-image" src="https://localhost/materialshub/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/silicon-sputtering-target.jpeg"></div>
        <div class="case-study-slide"><img class="case-study-slider-image" src="https://localhost/materialshub/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/zirconium-lump.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="case-study-slider-nav">
        <div class="case-study-nav-slide"><img class="case-study-slider-nav-image" src="https://localhost/materialshub/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/silicone-elastomer-tube.png"></div>
        <div class="case-study-nav-slide"><img class="case-study-slider-nav-image" src="https://localhost/materialshub/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/silicon-sputtering-target.jpeg"></div>
        <div class="case-study-nav-slide"><img class="case-study-slider-nav-image" src="https://localhost/materialshub/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/zirconium-lump.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, So I think I see what you're trying to do, but can I confirm: What are your conditions for breaking out the while? Are you saying you want it to process one row only, then close the div and open a new one, then continue processing the same row, then end the while, then go back to the beginning again? Can you post an short example of what the expected HTML will look like after ONE loop from the whiles?

Comment: @simonw16 - I have added the code to my question.

Weirdly when I ran the code today - it seems to ignore the fact I have already used the instances of the images and is now working as I expected. 

However, there must be a way to keep using the variable without having to re-write a while loop for every instance of the variable someone wishes to iterate through.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this?

```

```
<?php
    $image_urls = [];
    while (have_rows('case_study_image_gallery')): 
        the_row();
        $image_urls[] = get_sub_field('case_study_image');
    endwhile;
?>

<div class="case-study-slider">
    <?php foreach($image_urls as $image_url): ?>
        <div class="case-study-slide">
            <img class="case-study-slider-image" src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class="case-study-slider-nav">
    <?php foreach($image_urls as $image_url): ?>
        <div class="case-study-nav-slide">
            <img class="case-study-slider-nav-image" src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

```

Comment: This will process all the case-study-slides in a row, and all the case-study-nav-slides in a row separately. Is that what was intended? The code says "have a break, then continue while" which would suggest it needs to process just one case-study-slide then one-case-study-nav-slide, then the next case-study-slide then the next case-study-nav-slide. Or maybe I misunderstand

Comment: @cicakman I like this answer...
Also the first foreach loop I have had to use in PHP - so thanks for expanding my vocabulary a little more.

I need more reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your help!